# Python3 multiprocessing can only test a child process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

This is quite complex to explain, and a lot of code involve which I cannot paste here.

But I have a Test application which executes Test cases through designated plugins.

When the app is executed it creates a separate multi process called a writer, this module handles all updates to a web page which holds all running information about the test cases and their state.

For this write I also create an interface (WrIf). This interface hold a Queue to the Writer Thread together with a weakref.proxy().

Now when the Test app starts executing its Test cases it creates new multiprocessor from where it can call the specific plugin. That means that the WrIf is "serialized" to this multi-process.

For every call to the WrIf it makes a check to see if the main Writer thread is still running. however here is where I get a problem. I get the following assert when I try to call is_alive().

```
assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only test a child process'
AssertionError: can only test a child process
```

I can expand some on this however I think it will get muddy fast because the app is rather large and somewhat complex.

Regards

Comment: how do you acquire the `Process` object to check if it is alive? usually you can create `multiprocessing.Process` objects only by creating a new process but if somehow that is not the case you could try other methods from other modules to check if the process is running like psutil

Comment: I think I understand it now. The Writer "process" is created in the Main Thread which then becomes the parent, The main thread also creates the executions threads where the writer interface is passed to. IE i am trying to access a child process from another child process.

Comment: as long as your process is not very restricted, you can find the child processes using their pid and see if they still exist (and if they do they are still running)

Comment: Thank you. What I did instead was i move the alive chk back to Main thread. like a watchdog.